# CotntentProvider mime type clarification

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Is there any difference, from client's perspective, whether provider serves data with `item` or `dir` type? Does the framework use this information for optimization? Can you give examples of code where mime type matters? Could I just use `dir` mimetype for any case?

P.S. I know that dir = collection and item = row. And I read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#MIMETypeReference). Still, as a developer, I can't understand why should I bother differentiating `item` from `dir`. Isn't it just enough to use `dir`?

Comment: `dir` is for collections of content (think: table or view), `item` is for instances of content (think: row). Mostly, these MIME types are there to tie to activities that can work in support of the content itself. So, for example, the AOSP Contacts app has an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` of the relevant `item` MIME type.

Comment: Thanks. It clarified things a bit. So, there's a possibility of creating an activity and specifying `item` intent filter for it.

Comment: Correct. The `dir` one would work too, for activities designed to work with the collection type.